# regex for a sort field

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created a javascript sort function to sort a list of articles by title. I am going to convert all of the sortable words to capital letters so I do not have to deal with the differences associated with lower case and upper case. I am having trouble creating an expression though that wipes out all characters before the word that are not [A-Z]. I am not very familiar with regular expressions and any help would be appreciated. I am looking for something like this...

```
function cleanup(e) {
// delete leading not alphanum characters
// capitalize for sorting
//  str.replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, ''); 
return(e);
}
```

Comment: Could you post some sample input as well as sample output?

Comment: input would just be an article names all built into an array and them from there i perform the alphabetical sort to reorganize them. however, if the leading character is not a letter it screws with the order of precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `i` delimiter, the regular expression will be case insensitive, you might use this when you compare words.

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/5Rxs5/

Will replace all non a-zA-Z characters before the text:

```
var str = "#$DSFfd#_)#$$";

alert(str.replace(/[^a-z]+/i, ""))
```

If you want to remove all non a-zA-Z character do this (added the `g` delimiter, which means global):

```
var str = "#$DSFfd#_)#$$";

alert(str.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, ""))
```

**Uppercase first char**

```
var str = "#$abcd#_)#$$";
str = str.replace(/[^a-z]+/i,"");
str = str.match(/(^.)(.+)/);
str = str[1].toUpperCase() + str[2];

alert(str);
```

Alerts:

```
Abcd#_)#$$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/^[^a-z]+/i, '').toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace(/^[^\w\d]*/, '');`

tested using: http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: what is it that separates this replace from the one above as far as checking for characters?

Comment: only that mine also checks for numeric characters - as in the original question. Another alternative could be str.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*/, '');